# At what point does refactoring become not worth it?

Tags: refactoring, scalability, maintainability, rebuild

Say you have a program that currently functions the way it is supposed to. The application has very poor code behind it, eats up a lot of memory, is unscalable and would take major rewriting to implement any changes in functionality.

At what point does refactoring become less logical then a total rebuild?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Joel wrote a nice essay about this very topic:

[Things You Should Never Do, Part 1](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

The key lesson I got from this is that although the old code is horrible, hurts your eyes and your aesthetic sense, there's a pretty good chance that a lot of that code is patching undocumented errors and problems.  Ie., it has a lot of domain knowledge embedded in it and it will be difficult or impossible for you to replicate it.  You'll constantly be hitting against bugs-of-omission.

A book I found immensely useful is [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) by Michael C. Feathers.  It offers strategies and methods for approaching even truly ugly legacy code.

Comment: Fred Brooks said to "build one to throw away" - but he wasn't using agile techniques, and any functionality that was added was documented and understood, and so it was possible to rewrite without loss.

Comment: Not to mention that there are ALWAYS far more details you need to implement that you didn't think of when you sketched out the big project.

Answer (score 7):

One benefit of refactoring over rebuilding is that IF you can do refactoring step by step, i.e. in increments, you can test the increments in the context of the whole system, making development and debugging faster.

Old and deployed code, even when ugly and slow, has the benefit of having been tested thoroughly, and this benefit is lost if you start from scratch.

An incremental refactoring approach also has helps to ensure that there is always a product available which can be shipped (and it's improving constantly).

There is a nice article on the web about [how Netscape 6 was written from scratch and it was business-wise a bad idea](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).

Answer (score 6):

[Robert L. Glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Glass) suggests that

> [Modification of reused code is particularly error-prone. If more than 20 to 25 percent of a component is to be revised, it is more efficient and effective to write it from scratch.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321117425)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the simplest answer is if it will take longer to refactor than it will to rebuild, then you should just rebuild.

If it's a personal project then you might want to rebuild it anyway as you will probably learn more from building from scratch than you would from refactoring, and that's one big objective of personal projects.

However, in a professional time-limited environment, you should always go with whatever costs the company the least amount of money (for the same payoff) in the long run, which means choosing whichever takes less time.

Of course, it can be a little more complicated than that. If other people can be working on features while the refactoring is being done, then that might be a better choice over having everyone wait for a completely new version to be built. In that case rebuilding might take less time than *just* the refactoring would have taken, but you need to take the entire project and all contributors of the project in to account.

Answer (score 1):

When you spend more time refactoring than actually writing code.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where the software doesn't do what it's supposed to do.  Refactoring (changing the code without changing the functionality) makes sense if and only if the functionality is "as intended".

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with such applications in the past.  The best approach I've found is a gradual one:  When you are working on the code, find things that are done multiple times, group them together in functions.  Keep a notebook (you know, a real one, with paper, and a pencil or pen) so that you can mark your progress.  Use that in combination with your VCS, not instead of it.  The notebook can be used to provide an overview of the new functions you've created as part of the refactoring, and the VCS of course fills in the blanks for the details.

Over time, you will have consolidated a lot of code into more appropriate places.  Code duplication during this period of time is going to be next to impossible, so just do it as best as you can until you've reached a point where you can *really* start the refactoring process, auditing the entire code base and working on it as a whole.

If you've not enough time for that process (which will take a very long time), then rewriting from scratch using a test-first approach is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford the time to completely rebuild the app, don't need to improve functionality incrementally, and don't wish to retain any of the existing code then rewriting is certainly a viable alternative.  You can, on the other hand, use refactoring to do an incremental rewrite by slowly replacing the existing functions with equivalent functions that are better written and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is very small, then you can rewrite it from scratch. If the application is big, never do it. Rewrite it progressively, one step at a time validating you didn't break anything.

The application is the specification. If your rewrite it from scratch you will most likely run into a lots of insidious bugs because "no one knew that the call to this function was supposed to return 3 in that very specific case" (undocumented behaviour...).

It's always more fun to rewrite from scratch so your brain might trick you into thinking it's the right choice. Be careful, it's most likely not.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write unit tests to cover the existing application and then start to refactor it bit by bit, using the unit tests to make sure everything works as before.

In an ideal world you'd already have unit tests for the program, but given your comments about the quality of the app I'm guessing you don't...

Answer (score 0):

No document, no original writer, no test case, and a bunch of remaining bugs.

Answer (score 0):

[Uncle Bob weighs in](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/01/09/the-big-redesign-in-the-sky) with the following:

> **When is a redesign the right strategy?**
>
> I’m glad you asked that question. Here’s the answer. **Never.**
>
> Look, you made the mess, now clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve not had much luck with small incremental changes when the code I inherit is really bad. In theory the small incremental approach sounds good, but in practice all it ends up with is a better, but still poorly designed application that everyone thinks is now YOUR design.  When things break, people no longer think it is because of the previous code, it now becomes YOUR fault.  So, I would not use the word redesign, refactor or anything else that implies to a *manager type* that you are changing things to your way unless I was really going to do it my way.  Otherwise, even though you may have fixed dozens of problems, any problems that still existed (but weren’t discovered) are now going to be attributed to your rework.  And be assured that if the code is bad then your fixes will uncover a lot more bugs that were simply ignored before because the code was so bad to begin with.

If you truly know how to develop software systems then I would do a redesign of the whole system.  If you don’t TRULY know how to design GOOD software then I’d say stick with the small incremental changes as you may otherwise end up with a code base that is just as bad as the original.

One mistake that is often made when redesigning is that people ignore the original code base.  However, redesign does not have to mean totally ignore the old code.  The old code still had to do what your new code has to do, so in many cases the steps you need are already in the old code. Copy and Paste then tweak works wonders when redesigning systems.  I have found that in many cases, redesigning and rewriting an application and stealing snippets from the original code is far quicker and much more reliable than small incremental changes.